# python not found when deploying gcloud app

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting the error

exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH

when trying to run "cmd := exec.Command("python",..." in one of my functions within my main.go file. Not sure how else to include python than adding a "brew install python" command beforehand but seems troublesome to have to install python each time.

this is a golang app by the way and i am just integrating a python file into it for ease and time requirements, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think your running Windows ? (CMD) make sure python path is included in the path statement.

Comment: How to Edit The System Path in Windows 7, 8, & 10 https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/